# How to ssh into an EC2 without using the .pem file

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I want to ssh into an EC2 instance without using apem file i.e `ssh user@dns` instead of `ssh -i file.pem user@dns`. I did the following:

```
cp /location/of/.pem ~/.ssh/.pem
ssh-add ~/.pem
```

This works but only until I shut down the system.

I also added the .pem file to `~/.ssh/config` but it didnt work.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the permissions on ~/.ssh is 700 and owned by your user.
Files' permissions inside ~/.ssh should be 600

```
chown -R user: ~/.ssh
find ~/.ssh/ -type d -exec chmod 700 '{}' +
find ~/.ssh/ -type f -exec chmod 600 '{}' +
```

Add config to ~/.ssh/config like this:

```
Host friendly-alias
HostName host.example.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/.pem
User login-username
```

Then you should be able to do ssh friendly-alias and it'll log you in as login-username.